# Crystal reports keep sections together on same row

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to show two groups and details in the same row? My crystal report has two groups that I keep together.

The current output is:

```
LocName   Date  un1     un2 
-------------------------------
LocNAme  
        Date 
              compl     compl
              compl     compl
```

LocName and Date are grouped.

I would like the output to be:

```
LocName   Date  un1     un2 
-------------------------------
 LocNAme  Date  compl     compl
                compl     compl
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Grouping is on LOCNAME and DATE. To get your required output try below steps,

1] Bring LOCNAME and DATE column in details field. (Grouping should not be removed)

2] Right click on LOCNAME column and click **Format Field**.

3] Under **Common** tab check the checkbox which has label **Suppress If Duplicated**.

4] Follow similar steps for DATE column too.

5] Hide your two groups if you do not want to show group name in group headers.

I hope this helps!

Comment: please attach screenshot, then I will be able to help you further.

Comment: sir,,i checked this link,,now i got exact out put: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3293067

Answer (score 2):

At first right click of the report and go to "Report-->Selection expert". Go to the common tab. select your group heading name "LocName" from right side then check the "Underlay following section" option from common tab. then select "Date" group heading and also check the "Underlay following section". Now you will get your desire output.

Sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the group header from group 2 up next to your group header 1 and then suppress group 2. I don't think there is a way to display the details in the same line though. And since I don't know your data make sure after you do that that you still display the correct data.

Hope that helps,

Chris

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of a report with both groups and the detail section on the same line.
The way I did this is by suppressing group 1, putting the field that group 1 is grouped by in group header 2 and then creating a subreport that shows the detail section. The subreport is linked by the fields for group 1 and group 2.
[image]

Comment: if i moved group 2 up next to group header1 then group 2 data not show correctly

Comment: I just did a quick report using a date. I think because of the date you will have to do it this way: Suppress your Group 1 (LocName), then drag the LocName field into Group Header 2 and make it bold. Now you should see the LocName and Date next to each other with the details below. On Change of either date or LocName you should get a new group header. And again, I don't think you can put the details on the group header line unless you maybe use a subreport.

Comment: some time i have to show multiple locname..if do this.i can get proper report when ever i have to show multiple locName

Comment: If you group by location it will show you all data for one location and then show the next location.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your Group Header 2 from the Date Group up to Group Header 1 (LocName) to get them displayed in the same row. To get the Details also in the same row you will need to insert a subreport that shows the Compl data. Link that subreport to the LocName and you should be good to go.

EDIT: Since you can't put a subreport in a subreport, I guess the closest solution is to have both Group Headers on the same level and the Details below. Use Group 1 in your Main Report and then create a subreport with Group 2 and the Details. See added screenshot. The subreport has the border around it.

[image]

Comment: sir particular location i will show data in different date,,so if i move Group Header 2 Date Group to Group Header 1 ,that will not show different date data right

Comment: It will show data. Make sure to suppress Group 2(Date) after you move the Group Header 2 field to the Group Header 1 level. I added a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: in group1 i have to show different types of group2,,if i given like this i am getting only one date,,not getting different dates

Comment: Then try a subreport for Group 2 as well.

Comment: this time i try to give group1 "supress if duplicated" then also the group1 is repeting

Comment: Well, since CR is structured hierarchically, I guess the best you can do for your situation and data is get both Group Headers on the same level and then the details below that. I added an edit to my answer and provided another screenshot.

Comment: thise time where i have to add my sub report? i can add my sub report in details section or? some where else

Comment: You put the subreport in the Group Header 1.